# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined, smooth scrolling between two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a navigation and I have set it up so that it scrolls to elements on pageA and pageB. On the homepage if I click the dropdown menu for pageA, it successfully scrolls to whatever element on that page. However, when I click the dropdown for pageB, it comes up with this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
But when I'm on the homepage and I click the pageB dropdown menu, it successfully scrolls to any link I click. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(e){
        if(this.hash !== "") {
            e.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How come I am getting my error and how can I make the menu work between both pages?

TO CLARIFY: 
All of the menu options work from the home page only, but give the error when trying to go from pageA#anchor to pageB#anchor and vice versa. However if I am on pageB#anchor and I click on the pageA link, I can get to that page. The issue arises when I try to click on a dropdown link that goes to pageA#anchor that the issue arises. But this works fine form the homepage.

Comment: Your question says it doesn't work when you click Page B, then it says it does work when you click Page B. Are you saying all of the menu options work from the home page only, but give the error when trying to go from A to B or from B to A?

Comment: yes sorry, i should have been more clear. that is what i mean. however it works when i click just on pageB, but if i click on the link with pageB#anchor, it doesn't work. but if i click on pageB#anchor from the homepage, it does.

Comment: It seems to me that the JS shown would only work for links where the #anchor part refers to an element on the current page, that is, if you're already on page A and you try to link to pageA#anchor. Because the `click` event handler will be called *before* any navigation takes place, so before the other page opens. If `#anchor` doesn't match an element on the current page then `$(hash)` won't find any elements so `$(hash).offset()` will return `undefined`, hence the error message you quoted.

Comment: But it works from my homepage, which is a different page. That's what I can't figure out.